# How do you retrieve inner window handles in chrome/firefox + applications outside of yours?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, global, window-handles

There are a few PInvoke functions out there for grabbing window handles, but how do you grab the exact window handle that is in use: for example the richTextBox1 window within an app? or a Notepad.exe's textbox handle? Also text on webpages in chrome/firefox.

An example that grabs all three would be bad ass... most appreciated would be within Google Chrome or Firefox: whether it be textboxes or right on the *PAGE*.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling=true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetFocus();
```

that works for windows within the application itself, but it failed in notepad & in chrome

Comment: Perhaps the keyboard cursor has something to do with it? Mouse click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, `GetFocus` only works for window handles managed by the current thread's message queue. What you need to do is temporarily attach your message queue to another process:

1. Get the foreground window's handle with `GetForegroundWindow`.
2. Get the thread ID for your thread and the thread that owns the foreground window with `GetWindowThreadProcessId`.
3. Attach your message queue to the foreground window's thread with `AttachThreadInput`.
4. Call `GetFocus` which will return window handles from the foreground window's thread.
5. Disconnect from the foreground window's thread with `AttachThreadInput` again.

Something like this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class WindowUtils {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetWindowThreadProcessId(
        IntPtr hWnd,
        IntPtr ProcessId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr AttachThreadInput(
        IntPtr idAttach, 
        IntPtr idAttachTo,
        bool fAttach);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetFocus();

    public static IntPtr GetFocusedControl() {
        IntPtr activeWindowHandle = GetForegroundWindow();

        IntPtr activeWindowThread = 
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(activeWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero);
        IntPtr thisWindowThread =
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(this.Handle, IntPtr.Zero);

        AttachThreadInput(activeWindowThread, thisWindowThread, true);
        IntPtr focusedControlHandle = GetFocus();
        AttachThreadInput(activeWindowThread, thisWindowThread, false);

        return focusedControlHandle;
    }
}
```

(Source: [Control Focus in Other Processes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34752/Control-in-Focus-in-Other-Processes))

Comment: That narrows it down.. for some reason it doesn't pick up on much else besides TextBox Controls... no listboxes, no tree views, nothing on websites, that kind of thing

Comment: It could be that those controls are custom-drawn and managed by the application and not by the Win32 APIs, so they don't have window handles. In that case, the solution is going to be very application- and/or widget toolkit-dependent.

Comment: Web browsers routinely use non-windowed controls.